# Metasploit 3.4.1 Upadate issue

Tags: metasploit

I installed an old version of metasploit framework (which is 3.4.1) on ( windows 8). the problem is when I run msfupdate.bat I receive this message: 
svn: Working copy '.' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
- after cleanup (msf cleanup msf3/) another error apprears:
[*] Updating the Metasploit Framework...

Authentication realm: https://metasploit.com:443 =[ MSF must be updated via GitHub or a more recent msfupdate. See http://r-7.co/MSF-SVN for more ]=
Password for 'my PC name':

anyone had this issue before, please help

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution, just follow below steps:

If you are still on SVN, then converting to GitHub works like this:

1. **Don't try to use a password**; if by some miracle you happen to guess a correct one, your prize is that you get some messed up, out of date SVN-sourced code. (:
2. Delete your SVN checkout of Metasploit: `rm -rf $HOME/metasploit` (or the real path to your checkout).
3. Clone the latest from GitHub: `git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework metasploit` (or the path where you want the clone).
4. Go to your new Metasploit checkout, and run msfupdate: `cd metasploit; ./msfupdate` (this will get the bundle of Ruby gems together for you).

If you can't use the `git://` URI handler, then use `https://` instead. It's somewhat slower, but still a million times better than SVN. If bundler complains about gem dependencies, then check to make sure that you have a reasonable version of Ruby; 1.9.3 is ideal. 1.8.x is out. 2.0.0 should be okay, but it's not vetted for prime time yet.